# page up and page down alternative for horizontal scrolling in less

Tags: linux, terminal, less

In vertical scrolling using `less` the page up and page down keys are working. Which keys scrolls one page down/up vertically? The `less` was started with `-S` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man less`:

> -# or --shift
>
> Specifies the default number of positions to scroll horizontally in the RIGHTARROW and LEFTARROW commands.  If  the number specified is zero, it sets the default number of positions to one half of the screen width.  Alternately, the number may be specified as a fraction of the width of the screen, starting with a decimal point:  .5  is half of the screen width, .3 is three tenths of the screen width, and so on.

So you may run `less -S -#.9999` if you want to scroll "almost a full page" left or right, by hitting left or right arrow key (`Esc-(` and `Esc-)` should work as well)